# Бот на PHP для Discord

Tags: php, бот, discord-api

Здравствуйте, у меня есть код бота:

`include __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

`$discord = new Discord([
    'token' => 'token',
]);`

`$discord->on('ready', function ($discord) {
    echo "Bot is ready.", PHP_EOL;`

```
$discord->on('message', function ($message) {
    if($message->content = '!online'){
        echo "Recieved a message from {$message->author->username}: {$message->content}", PHP_EOL;}});});
```

`$discord->run();`

Я установил Composer, добавил туда DiscordPHP, а как сделать так, чтобы данный код выполнялся постоянно.

Comment: пхп не предназначен для постоянной работы одного скрипта. Но решения есть 2: либо CRON, либо рекурсите вызов скрипта. Советую еще посмотреть в сторону времени выполнения скрипта - этот параметр тоже настраивается.

Comment: Пожалуй без потока или демона, крона - никак, хотя рекурсия, может делать довольно неплохие повторения через `sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

Запускай из под CLI этот скрипт.
Например

```
screen php thisScript.php
```

Этот файл взят отсюда, я так полагаю - https://github.com/teamreflex/DiscordPHP

Там же первый пункт FAQ:

```
Can I run DiscordPHP on a webserver (e.g. Apache, nginx)?
No, DiscordPHP will only run in CLI. If you want to have an interface for your bot you can integrate react/http with your bot and run it through CLI.
```